# Is deciding whether changing one entry decreases the permanent of a matrix in the polynomial hierarchy?

Tags: permanent

Consider the following problem: given a matrix $M\in\{-m,\dots,0,\dots,m\}^{n\times n}$, indices $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and an integer $a$. Replace $M[i,j]$ by $a$ and call new matrix $\hat M$. Is $per(M)>per(\hat M)$?

Is this problem in the polynomial hierarchy?

Comment: It can be solved by two calls to a #P oracle... If it was in PH, then it would imply that PP is also in PH... However, if PP is in PH, then PH collapses. So I think it is unlikely that it is in PH.

Comment: @TayfunPay I don't think that argument is correct. The problem can be solved with 2 calls to #P, but it cannot be ruled out so easily that there's a simpler algorithm that might show it's in PH. You'd have to show it's hard for #P for that, e.g. by reducing Permanent to it.

Comment: If you plug in the definition of the permanent and simplify the resulting inequality, your problem boils down to the question whether the permanent of a given (n-1)-by-(n-1) matrix is strictly positive.

Comment: @Gamow, and the other way around, ie deciding if $PER(M) > 0$ can be reduced to this problem. Given a matrix $M$, construct $M'$ by adding a line on top and a column on the left with a 1 in the top-left corner and 0 otherwise. Now let $M''$ be the matrix $M'$ where the top left entry has been replaced by $-1$. Then $PER(M'') = -PER(M') = -PER(M)$ by multilinearity and developing the first column. Thus $PER(M) > 0$ iff the problem of Turbo on $M'$, $(i,j) = (0,0)$ and $a = -1$ returns true.

Comment: @holf: I think you should post this as an answer. It pretty definitively answers the question, and then the question won't appear as "unanswered" any more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to testing, given $M$, whether $PER(M) > 0$.

**Proof**: Assume you are given $M$ and you want to decide whether $PER(M) > 0$. We construct $M'$ as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & & & & \\
    \dots & & M & &\\
    0 & & & &
\end{bmatrix}
It is easy to see that $PER(M) = PER(M')$. Now, define $\hat{M'}$ to be $M'$ where we replace the $(0,0)$ entry of $M'$ by $-1$. By multilinearity, it follows that $PER(M) = PER(M') = -PER(\hat{M'})$. Thus $PER(M) > 0$ if and only if $PER(M') > PER(\hat{M'})$.

Now assume you are given $M$, $(i,j)$ and $a$ and define $\hat{M}$ as in your question, that is, by changing $M[i,j]$ to $a$. We have
\begin{align}
PER(M) > & PER(\hat{M}) \text{ iff} \\
\sum_{\sigma} \prod_{k=1}^n M[k,\sigma(k)] > &\sum_{\sigma} \prod_{k=1}^n \hat{M}[k,\sigma(k)] \text{ iff} \\
\sum_{\sigma, \sigma(i)=j} M[i,j] \prod_{k \neq i}^n M[k,\sigma(k)] > &\sum_{\sigma, \sigma(i)=j} a \prod_{k \neq i}^n M[k,\sigma(k)] \text{ iff}\\
(M[i,j]-a) \cdot \sum_{\sigma, \sigma(i)=j} \prod_{k \neq i}^n M[k,\sigma(k)] > & 0 \text{ iff}\\
(M[i,j]-a) \cdot PER(M') > 0
\end{align}

where $M'$ is the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from $M$ by removing line $i$ and column $j$. $\square$

Comment: Good answer, but it’s probably worth explicitly stating the answer to the OP’s question as well.